# What are "derivationally related forms" in WordNet?

Tags: nlp, wordnet

WordNet lemmas can have *derivationally related forms*. For instance, the noun "butter" (meaning the spread you put on bread) is deemed to be derivationally-related to the verb "butter" (meaning the act of spreading butter on bread):

```py
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>>
>>> wn.lemma('butter.n.01.butter')
Lemma('butter.n.01.butter')
>>> wn.lemma('butter.n.01.butter').synset().definition()
u'an edible emulsion of fat globules made by churning milk or cream; for cooking and table use'
>>> wn.lemma('butter.n.01.butter').derivationally_related_forms()
[Lemma('butter.v.01.butter'), Lemma('buttery.s.02.buttery'), Lemma('butyraceous.a.01.butyraceous')]
>>> wn.lemma('butter.n.01.butter').derivationally_related_forms()[0]
Lemma('butter.v.01.butter')
>>> wn.lemma('butter.n.01.butter').derivationally_related_forms()[0].synset().definition()
u'spread butter on'
>>>
>>> wn.lemma('flood.n.01.flood').synset().definition()
u'the rising of a body of water and its overflowing onto normally dry land'
>>> wn.lemma('flood.n.01.flood').derivationally_related_forms()
[Lemma('flood.v.04.flood'), Lemma('deluge.v.01.flood'), Lemma('flood.v.02.flood')]
>>> wn.lemma('flood.n.01.flood').derivationally_related_forms()[0]
Lemma('flood.v.04.flood')
>>> wn.lemma('flood.n.01.flood').derivationally_related_forms()[0].synset().definition()
u'become filled to overflowing'
>>>
```

However, it's not clear precisely what the term "derivationally related" means. For instance, I could argue that "television" and "telescope" are "derivationally related", since both words are derived from the Ancient Greek "têle", meaning "far". But WordNet disagrees:

```py
>>> wn.lemma('telescope.n.01.telescope').derivationally_related_forms()
[Lemma('telescopic.s.01.telescopic'), Lemma('telescopic.s.02.telescopic')]
```

What precisely, then, is WordNet's definition of a *"derivationally related form"*? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: If you are planning to do anything serious with WordNet, and/or care about the design decisions, the big yellow book is worth a read: https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/wordnet  (Surprisingly, reasonably priced!)   It is fairly old (1998!), but gives a good basis to then go and read all the papers from the Wordnet conferences, and other research, as well as understand the changes from version to version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [WordNet glossary](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wngloss7wn):

> **derivationally related forms**:
>   Terms in different syntactic categories that have the same root form and are semantically related.

The verb "to butter" has the same [root form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_(linguistics)) as the noun "butter", they are different syntactic categories (verb vs. noun), and they're clearly semantically related.

On the other hand, "television" and "telescope" do not have the same root form (but e.g. "to televise" would have the same root as "television", and "telescopic" has the same root as "telescope"). Moreover, they are not semantically related, and they are both nouns.

Comment: Sweet, this gives me near-total clarity. The only thing I'm not sure of is how the "root form" is a word is defined here, since it's not in their glossary. An edit to clarify that (or just a link to a rigorous definition somewhere) would make this answer fully comprehensive.

Comment: @MarkAmery Wikipedia is as close as I can get. This being linguistics, not mathematics, an ironclad definition is probably hard to come by.

Comment: This also provides nice mapping for *agent of an act* to *the act*, e.g. "planner" to "to plan".